# Need help, need to count the number of negative values inside a linked list, C++

Tags: c++

So I am working through an assignment on an online course and I need some help programming a way to count the number of negative values inside a linked list in C++.

Here is the code I have right now along with one of my attempted awnsers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class IntNode {
public:
   IntNode(int dataInit = 0, IntNode* nextLoc = nullptr);
   void InsertAfter(IntNode* nodePtr);
   IntNode* GetNext();
   int GetDataVal();
private:
   int dataVal;
   IntNode* nextNodePtr;
};

// Constructor
IntNode::IntNode(int dataInit, IntNode* nextLoc) {
   this->dataVal = dataInit;
   this->nextNodePtr = nextLoc;

   return;
}

/* Insert node after this node.
 * Before: this -- next
 * After:  this -- node -- next
 */
void IntNode::InsertAfter(IntNode* nodeLoc) {
   IntNode* tmpNext = nullptr;

   tmpNext = this->nextNodePtr;    // Remember next
   this->nextNodePtr = nodeLoc;    // this -- node -- ?
   nodeLoc->nextNodePtr = tmpNext; // this -- node -- next

   return;
}

// Grab location pointed by nextNodePtr
IntNode* IntNode::GetNext() {
   return this->nextNodePtr;
}

int IntNode::GetDataVal() {
   return this->dataVal;
}

int main() {
   IntNode* headObj = nullptr; // Create intNode objects
   IntNode* currObj = nullptr;
   IntNode* lastObj = nullptr;
   int i = 0;
   int negativeCntr = 0;

   headObj = new IntNode(-1);        // Front of nodes list
   lastObj = headObj;

   for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {        // Append 10 rand nums
      currObj = new IntNode((rand() % 21) - 10);
      lastObj->InsertAfter(currObj); // Append curr
      lastObj = currObj;             // Curr is the new last item
   }

   currObj = headObj;                // Print the list
   while (currObj != nullptr) {
      cout << currObj->GetDataVal() << ", ";
      currObj = currObj->GetNext();
   }
   cout << endl;

   currObj = headObj;                // Count number of negative numbers
   while (currObj != nullptr) {

      /* Your solution goes here  */
    if (currObj > 0)
    {
        negativeCntr++;
    }    

      currObj = currObj->GetNext();
   }
   cout << "Number of negatives: " << negativeCntr << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

I am not sure what syntaxes to use in this case, I prowled around the book for some solutions but could not find anything.

Comment: if (currObj->GetDataVal < 0) negativeCntr++;

Comment: Throw away `IntNode`, use `std::list` instead, then do `auto const count = std::count_if(begin(list), end(list), [](auto num) { return num < 0; });`.

Comment: Seriously, an on-line C++ course shouldn't try to get beginners to write linked-list classes.  The success rate of beginners writing a linked-list class properly and without error in C++ is almost 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like the easiest way to do it.

```
if(currObj->GetDataVal() < 0) negativeCntr++;
```

Comment: Yup that did the trick, my previous attempt was close I just needed to get currObj to access the data list with the access operator, now I know how to do it.